# phpmail gmail Could not connect to SMTP

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer

Tried using the code below which has been working for years until last week. Some change on Gmail side perhaps. But its just not working even if various combinations are tried.
  Allow unsafe apps is ON still unable to connect SMTP

```
<?php
sendMail("tosomeid@gmail.com", "fromsomeid@gmail.com", "test", "test msg<br>hello!");

function sendMail($to, $from, $subject, $message) {   
    try {
        //$to='tosomeid@gmail.com';
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From:' . $from . ' <fromsomeid@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
        ini_set("sendmail_from", "fromsomeid@gmail.com");
        require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
        require_once("class.smtp.php");
        set_time_limit(240);
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP 
        $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Port = 587; // or 587                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $mail->Username = "fromsomeid@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
        $mail->Password = "password123"; // SMTP account password
        $mail->From = "fromsomeid@gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

        $mail->AddAddress("tosomeid@gmail.com");
        $mail->SetFrom('fromsomeid@gmail.com', $from);
        $mail->AddReplyTo("fromsomeid@gmail.com", $from);
        $mail->AddBCC("tosomeid@gmail.com");
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $message;
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        echo 'sendMail to=>' . $to;
        if (!$mail->Send()) {
            echo 'Message was not sent.';
            echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo '<br>Message was sent successfully to selected recipients.';
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {

        echo'EXCEPTION <br>';
        echo '<br>Caught exception: ' . $ex->getMessage() . "\n".$ex->getTraceAsString();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to post the actual error. It’s not a problem with your code. It’s likely to be a problem with a recent change in Gmail’s root CA certificate. Search for questions on that subject as it has been answered several times recently.

Comment: I Looked for lot of comments I also added the CA certificate cacert.pem but still it didn't work. keeps showing  Could not connect to SMTP host. 

Error is as given below sendMail to=>togmail@gmail.comSMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f23sm26136426pfk.71 - gsmtp
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, .. 250-
hel...') #2 class.phpmailer.php(763): PHPMailer->PostSend() #3 mailtest.php(36): PHPMailer->Send() #4 mailtest.php(3): sendMail('togmail@gmail....', 'frommailid@gma...', 'test', 'test msg
hel...') #5 {main}

Comment: I tried a sample .NET code strangely it is working without any issue. But same thing not working with PHPmailer. Same port same settings, same email, same server. But it doesn't work with PHP.

Comment: Don’t put debug output in comments. Add it to your question. .NET has an entirely different runtime. This is a PHP problem, not specifically a PHPMailer problem.

Comment: There is something about gmail. We are able to send the mail using same code for other domains.

Comment: Yes, because other domains have signatures signed by root certificates that *are* in your existing CA bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You add SMTPOption to config Phpmailer

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
)
```

);

Comment: Tried that, no change it still gives following error
Caught exception: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. #0